# How can I get an attribute out of a tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using Beautiful Soup to extract specific data out of a webpage.
I tried to get an attribute of a specific tag, but I failed.
I have to extract the attribute `'title'` from the tag.

Here is the specific html tag I tried to get the attribute from:

```
<span id="currwx_icon" style="display: block;" class="weather_icon1 wxico_l_23a" title="Cloudy"></span>
```

Here are the codes I ran:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://worldweather.wmo.int/en/city.html?cityId=206')
data = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

today_weather = data.select('#currwx_icon')
for info in today_weather:
    print(info['title'])
```

In this case, I get an error

> KeyError: 'title'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://worldweather.wmo.int/en/city.html?cityId=206')
data = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

today_weather = data.select('#currwx_icon')
for info in today_weather:
    print(info.attrs)
```

In this case, it does return a list of attributes but the attribute `title` is omitted

> {'id': 'currwx_icon', 'class': ['weather_icon1'], 'style': 'display: block;'}

This is the webpage I am trying to extract data from:
https://worldweather.wmo.int/en/city.html?cityId=206

What am I missing here???
And thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content is served dynamically based on data from additional XHR request and browser / js is manipulating the DOM. Try to use this structured data instead, you will find a lot of information via:

- present data: https://worldweather.wmo.int/en/json/present.xml
- forecast data (additional): https://worldweather.wmo.int/en/json/206_en.xml

##### Example

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://worldweather.wmo.int/en/json/present.xml').json()['present']
for k in data:
    if data[k]['cityId'] == 206:
        print(data[k])
```

##### Output

```
{'cityId': 206, 'stnId': '27612', 'stnName': 'MOSKVA VDNH', 'issue': '202209200900', 'temp': 12, 'rh': 78, 'wxdesc': 'Cloudy', 'wxImageCode': '23', 'wd': 'S', 'ws': '1.0', 'iconNum': '2301', 'sundate': '20220920', 'sunrise': '06:10', 'sunset': '18:34', 'moonrise': '', 'moonset': '', 'daynightcode': 'a'}
```

Comment: This is correct. The HTTP response does not contain the searched element.